# Include custom text in glossary

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'd like to include a disclaimer like "This list of acronyms only specifies the most important ones" underneath the caption of the acronym page. I'm currently inserting the page using

```
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=list]
```

Is there any way to include custom paragraphs using this command?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `\setglossarypreamble` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\setglossarypreamble[acronym]{This list of acronyms only
specifies the most important ones}

\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{sample acronym}

\begin{document}
\gls{abc}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

For older versions of `glossaries` you need to redefine `\glossarypreamble` before you display the list of acronyms.

```
\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{This list of acronyms only
specifies the most important ones}
```